# Count number of times a word shows up in a two column array in awk

Tags: awk, multiple-columns

How can I count how many times a word shows up within two columns of an array in awk? (The same word can show up on either column, but I would need both to add one to the count). Then, I need to print each word with the number of times it appears.
For example, part of it could be:

```
Sarah Jenny
Carlos Javi
Jenny Mark
Calab Charles
Charles Jenny
```

and I would need to print out

```
Sarah 1
Jenny 3
Carlos 1
Javi 1
Mark 1
Charles 2
```

Comment: Seems you have already asked several awk questions, then what have you tried for this?

Comment: well I removed what I had... so it is no longer in my code.
I tried creating some kind of variable that would add 1 whenever a word appeared... but I think I mainly had issues because there are two columns in the array @BMW

Comment: why not put the code back, then ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array and store the names and indices. Later iterate over the array and print our names and their counts. Something like:

```
awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)count[$x]++}END{for(name in count) print name,count[name]}' file
```

```
$ cat file
Sarah Jenny
Carlos Javi
Jenny Mark
Calab Charles
Charles Jenny
```

```
<~/Temp>$ awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)count[$x]++}END{for(name in count) print name,count[name]}' file
Javi 1
Mark 1
Carlos 1
Calab 1
Charles 2
Sarah 1
Jenny 3
```

Comment: **Note:** Use `count[tolower($x)]++` to allow case insensitive counting.

Answer (score 1):

A `gnu awk` version

```
awk -v RS=" |\n" '{a[$1]++} END { for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
Calab 1
Charles 2
Mark 1
Jenny 3
Sarah 1
Javi 1
Carlos 1
```

If you like it sorted, you can add `| sort -nrk 2`

This solution breaks opp all line, so every word comes on new line.
This makes counting more simple.

If its unsure if its space or tabs, change to  `RS="[[:space:]]+|\n"`
And like jaypal writes, to ignore case, use `a[tolower($1)]++`

Due to multiple character in `RS` you need `gnu awk`

---

All included

```
awk -v RS="[[:space:]]+|\n" '{a[tolower($1)]++} END { for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file | sort -nrk 2
jenny 3
charles 2
sarah 1
mark 1
javi 1
carlos 1
calab 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If input file has just those two columns which you want work with. Then this should be enough to do the work

```
chidori@ubuntu:~$ cat input.txt
Sarah Jenny
Carlos Javi
Jenny Mark
Calab Charles
Charles Jenny

chidori@ubuntu:~$ tr -s ' ' '\n' < input.txt | sort | uniq -c
      1 Calab
      1 Carlos
      2 Charles
      1 Javi
      3 Jenny
      1 Mark
      1 Sarah
chidori@ubuntu:~$
```